# Undirected Graph adjacency (Computer Science)

Tags: graph, matrix, computer-science, tree-nodes

I have an undirected graph G=(V,E) with nodes labelled 1, 2, 3,...,n, and a specific node k in V.

I have two representations of this graph: [Adjacency-Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) and [Adjacency-List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)

How would I go about figuring out if node k is adjacent to all other nodes in the graph? This is part of a bigger problem that I have.

I don't want concrete pseudocode or solution, just in plain English what I would scan in the data structure and how I would determine this. (Please keep the complexity as low as possible)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just check every node and return false if any of them is not adjacent to k. I don't think you can avoid checking every vertex so doing a short-circuit fail would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

using adj matrices, check row `k` to be 1 in all components but the `k`-th.

using adj lists (assuming you do not have a multigraph and `n` is the number of graph vertices), check for list size `n-1`, which should be O(1).

best regards, carsten